# how to change background color of Qwidget irrespective of its parents background color

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom Qwidget and I have to change its backbround color rather than its parents background color. My code does not work.

How can I achieve it?
 my code is

```
QFrame *frame = new QFrame(ui->frame);
QPalette palette;

palette.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::red);
frame->setFixedSize(240,240);
frame->setPalette(palette);
frame->setAutoFillBackground(true);
frame->show();
```

Comment: Could you add more details to the explanation?

Comment: Actually I want to change the background color of custom Qframe, its parent is Qframe which is transparent, if I try to set background color to child Qframe it is always transparent and not what I am setting, I tried pallete.setBrush function but still same output

Comment: What is the style that you are using? Try `QPalette::Window` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just added `frame->setStyleSheet("background:black;")`;
and its done

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried style sheets?

Something like:

```
QFrame *frame = new QFrame(ui->frame);

frame->setFixedSize(240,240);
frame->setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");
frame->show();
```

Comment: Yes, I did but still same output