# Changing the color of a QFrame in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qframe

I have set the color of my main window in QT to be grey.

```
ui(new Ui ::MainWindow)
ui-> setupUi(this)
this->setStyleSheet("background-color: grey;");
```

I have tried multiple ways to set the color of the QFrame, however it takes on the default grey color that I have set. One way I tried is below.

```
ui->frame->setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255,255,255)");
```

I have tried to change the color of the QFrame by using the setStyleSheet method but no matter which color I assign it remains grey. I have tried setting the background, border, and color. Is there any way to do this that I am overlooking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change background color of Qwidget irrespective of its parents background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538345/how-to-change-background-color-of-qwidget-irrespective-of-its-parents-background)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the background color of the QFrame.

Set the QFrame's style sheet to the following:

```
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"
```

Comment: The issue I am having with this is that I want to only set the border color  of the QFrame.                                                                                                          I am attempting to set it like this ui->frame->setStyleSheet("QFrame{border: 5px solid black; }");

Answer (score 4):

Set a MainWindow (not the QFrame) StyleSheet like this:

```
QMainWindow{
   background-color: gray
}
QFrame { 
   border: 5px solid black 
}
```

This worked for me:

```
mainwindow->setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color: gray} QFrame { border: 5px solid black } ");
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python (PyQt) users:

```
frame = QFrame(self)
frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(50,50,50)')
```

Comment: slight mistake here is you have to use double quotes `"` not single quoutes`'`

Answer (score 0):

This troubled me quite some time. Before setting the actual stylesheet unset it first:

```
    ui->frame->setStyleSheet("");
    ui->frame->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255,255,255)");
```

For more customisation options have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html and for larger projects you might want to think about setting up global stylesheets for your app.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ui->frame->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(251, 255, 206);");
```